# Case Insensitive search from find command?

Tags: linux, find

I am not able to figure out how can I do case-insensitive search using the `find` command.

I tried

```
find . -name -i pattern
```

And it does not work.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Use this:

```
find . -iname PatTeRn -print
```

Comment: 1. Providing the `-print` flag is redundant because if omitted, this is actually the default behavior. 2. TIL that the double quotes around the search term are optional.

Answer (score 44):

I believe it's: `find . -iname pattern`

From `man find`:

```
-iname pattern
       Like  -name, but the match is case insensitive.
```

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo updatedb

locate -i "nameofthefile"
```

`nameofthefile` should be without the inverted commas.

Comment: It is notable that this is the fastest method for system-wide searches.